# JavaScript - Cycle through months and years, performing action each time

Tags: javascript, date

I have a start year and month, for instance December 2007, and an end year and month, for instance December 2015. The start date and end date may be the same date.

How do I cycle through each month and call a function each time?

Thanks.

Comment: post your code what you tried

Comment: Have you tried anything which is not working or something ? Do not expect others to do entire code from scratch for you..

Comment: you wnt month count ? use moment

Comment: Sorry for the waste of time. But I figured it out on my own. Can I close this?

Comment: @posfan12   yes you can delete this question :D

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

### Convert to total monthes

I would do the following: convert monthes \ years to an integer value, which expresses the number of monthes passed from the beginning of Common Era. Then, you can easily iterate through it.

Here is the working snippet:

```js
function iterateThroughMonthes(monthFrom, yearFrom, monthTo, yearTo, callback)
{
  var totalMonthFrom = yearFrom * 12 + (monthFrom - 1);
  var totalMonthTo = yearTo * 12 + (monthTo - 1);
  
  for (var i = totalMonthFrom; i <= totalMonthTo; i++) {
    callback(Math.floor(i / 12), i % 12 + 1);
  }
}

// From June, 2014 to December, 2015
iterateThroughMonthes(6, 2014, 12, 2015, function(m, y) { 
    document.body.innerHTML += m + "." + y + "<br/>";
});
```

### While loop

You can make a simply `while` loop which will iterate through monthes.

```js
function iterateThroughMonthes(monthFrom, yearFrom, monthTo, yearTo, callback)
{
  while (yearFrom < yearTo || yearFrom === yearTo && monthFrom <= monthTo)
  {
    callback(monthFrom++, yearFrom);
    if (monthFrom === 13)
    {
     monthFrom = 1;
        yearFrom++;
    }
  }
}

// From June, 2014 to December, 2015
iterateThroughMonthes(6, 2014, 12, 2015, function(m, y) { 
    document.body.innerHTML += m + "." + y + "<br/>";
});
```

Also, you can use JavaScript **`Date`** object.

Answer (score 0):

**use Moment**

```js
var month = (moment(moment('1/12/2015')).diff(moment(moment('1/12/2007')), 'month'))

for (var i=0;i<month;i++){
console.log("ssss")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
var date_start = new Date(2007, 11)     // remember months start with 0
var date_end = new Date(2015, 11)       // remember months start with 0
var date_count = date_start
while (date_count <= date_end)
{
    alert(date_count.toString())
    date_count.setMonth(date_count.getMonth() + 1)
}
```